# Trying to apply advanced filter using range as input from a dialog box?

Tags: vba, excel

Getting an error in the advanced filter line of code. Object doesn't support this property or method.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select range or enter A1 notation:", Type:=8)

Workbooks(filename).Sheets("Sheet1").rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "A1:A2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A3"), Unique:=False
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to define the workbook and sheet as that's already being defined as a range when you set range. Change code:

```
Rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
    "A1:A2"), CopyToRange:=Range("A3"), Unique:=False
```